# Oracle SQL: Display row number for rows grouped by a column

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following dataset:

[image]

What I would like is for this result:

[image]

I've tried using DENSE_RANK but got nowhere fast. I've read through a few stack overflow pages but am now staring at a blank sheet as I can't get anything to work.

Any ideas? Pointers?

**EDIT**

This seems to be ok so far - any obvious issues?

```
SELECT Person_id,
    PERSON_NUMBER,
    EFFECTIVE_START_DATE,
    EFFECTIVE_END_DATE,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Person_id ORDER BY Person_id) YEAH
FROM PER_ALL_PEOPLE_F
```

Comment: what's the logic? what have you tried so far?

Comment: I've tried what I mentioned in my question

Comment: order by effective_start_date, then you're ready to go

Answer (score 0):

If my assumption is right then you want to fetch the individual person's record in chronological order.

```
SELECT
    PERSON_ID,
    PERSON_NUMBER,
    EFFECTIVE_START_DATE,
    EFFECTIVE_END_DATE,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(
        PARTITION BY PERSON_ID
        ORDER BY
            EFFECTIVE_START_DATE
    ) YEAH
FROM
    <YOUR TABLE>
ORDER BY PERSON_ID, YEAH
```

**Note:** 
I know this table and even worked on it.
Please edit your question and remove the table name from your question. It's a bad practice to reveal the table name on the WEB. Column names are fine but not a table name.